# Cache update error using playbook

Tags: apt, ubuntu-22.04

I keep getting this error when running my playbook on Ubuntu 22.04LTS server and have been trying to fix it for sometime now but aren't making progress.

> fatal: [MY IP]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Failed to update apt cache: W:Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default., W:See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details., W:GPG error: https://pkg.jenkins.io/debian-stable binary/ Release: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 5BA**********5CA, E:The repository 'https://pkg.jenkins.io/debian-stable binary/ Release' is not signed."}

Comment: How did you import the public gpg key for the repository?

Comment: And what does your sources.list for jenkins look like?

Comment: I used the commands:

curl -fsSL https://pkg.jenkins.io/debian-stable/jenkins.io.key | sudo tee \
  /usr/share/keyrings/jenkins-keyring.asc > /dev/null

echo deb [signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/jenkins-keyring.asc] \
  https://pkg.jenkins.io/debian-stable binary/ | sudo tee \
  /etc/apt/sources.list.d/jenkins.list > /dev/null

Comment: Please edit addition information in the question, it's unreadable in the comments.

Comment: And please show what your configuration files look like, don't just copy the commands from the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

The PGP key you downloaded is wrong.

The [current installation instructions](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/installing/linux/#debianubuntu) contain this command for the import:

```
curl -fsSL https://pkg.jenkins.io/debian/jenkins.io-2023.key | sudo tee \
  /usr/share/keyrings/jenkins-keyring.asc > /dev/null
```

You used an older URL which is missing the `-2023` in the key filename.